# How to detect if the user is dragging nodes from another virtual treeview?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

In the `OnDragOver` or `OnDragDrop` events, how to check if the user is dragging nodes of the same Virtual Treeview or of another?

`DragType` is `dtVCL`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both events, you have arguments `Sender` and `Source`. `Sender` is the component sending the event, that is the tree above which the mouse is flying, the drag receiver. The `Source` is the tree from which the drag is coming.

You can cast the Sender or Source to the actual tree you use.

```
Memo1.Lines.Add(TVirtualStringTree(Sender).Name);
Memo1.Lines.Add(TVirtualStringTree(Source).Name);
```

Comment: I didn't know why I tried several other indirect, failed approaches and perfectly missed the `Source` parameter... Thank you very much!